# How to create test account with PayPal Payments Pro (Use to represent yourself as a merchant using Pro) option selected in sandbox?

Tags: api, paypal, sandbox

I am unable to create Paypal sandbox test account with option PayPal Payments Pro (Use to represent yourself as a merchant using Pro). I selected the option during test account creation  but when I viewed the details of that account, then it displayed

```
Account Type : Seller (Use to represent yourself as the merchant).
```

Please help me as I am unable to do credit card payment integration using sandbox as it is showing

**error** :

```
Array
(
    [TIMESTAMP] => 2013-02-06T10:40:57Z
    [CORRELATIONID] => 2732f8af3ec70
    [ACK] => Failure
    [VERSION] => 85.0
    [BUILD] => 5060305
    [L_ERRORCODE0] => 10501
    [L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Invalid Configuration
    [L_LONGMESSAGE0] => This transaction cannot be processed due to an invalid merchant configuration.
    [L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error
    [AMT] => 100.00
    [CURRENCYCODE] => USD
)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you go to create the account on developer.paypal.com, try setting Country to Canada instead of United States.

Answer (score 0):

The API credentials in the Sandbox environment uses the default buyer account you have. You need to make sure to use the “payments pro” option when you create a buyer account in the sandbox environment. You’ll then see a new set of API credentials under API credentials…

Steps below:

1. Go to the link https://developer.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/devscr?cmd=_sandbox-acct-session and login with your sandbox credentials
2. And click on the link Preconfigured which will take you to https://developer.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/devscr?cmd=_create-account-session
3. From the options select Website Payments Pro (Use to represent yourself as a merchant using Pro) and create a Test Account and use these details for sandbox

Comment: Hi Vikas,thanks for the valuable response.My problem is that I am unable to create test account with option PayPal Payments Pro (Use to represent yourself as a merchant using Pro). That is my problem.

Comment: have you created businees account on sandbox?

Comment: Yes Vikas,I created the business account but nothing works.
I am having options for Account Type : Buyer (Use to represent your customer's experience) Buyer In-Store (Use to represent your customer's experience with in-store checkout enabled) Seller (Use to represent yourself as the merchant) PayPal Payments Pro (Use to represent yourself as a merchant using Pro)

Comment: check my updated answer and choose  PayPal Payments Pro (Use to represent yourself as a merchant using Pro) when you create business a/c for paypal pro

Comment: I tried a lot and selected every time the option  PayPal Payments Pro (Use to represent yourself as a merchant using Pro)  as account type but on view details of test account, it shows   Seller (Use to represent yourself as the merchant) as account type.

Comment: check my updated answer , create once again business a/c and try, tell me if you have further problem

Comment: I got this response from Paypal regarding sandbox feature for the option PayPal Payments Pro (Use to represent yourself as a merchant using Pro) as account type : There is currently a known issue with creating or enabling payments pro on sandbox accounts that the engineers are working to address. We apologize for any inconvenience this may have caused. We are aware of this issue and are actively working to resolve it. As soon as we are aware that the problem has been resolved, we will notify you by replying to this email.

Comment: Is there any update on this? I still dont see an option to create a payments pro