# Creating sandbox paypal pro account

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

i have some difficulties creating test account in sandbox. I found some similar topics but i still can't understand what to do.
For example this one "[How to create test account with PayPal Payments Pro (Use to represent yourself as a merchant using Pro) option selected in sandbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14728677/how-to-create-test-account-with-paypal-payments-pro-use-to-represent-yourself-a)"

It says login in developers site, ok, done with that. Then "click on the link Preconfigured". What link? I can't find it. It just does not exist on that page and on any other that i searched.

Why i cannot login to https://www.sandbox.paypal.com with my seller account from sandbox, but it's possible to login using clients accounts (personal) from sandbox.

Do i need to apply to Paypal Payments Pro after i registered my sandbox account, and if i need why do i get "Service is not responding due to an internal error. Please contact customer service at +1-888-883-9770.". Also what social security number do i have to use(i just want to check integration with paypal, i dont have any bank accounts or social security numbers. i'm not even from usa)?

Do i need to accept licence agreement and where can i find it? According to this document https://ppmts.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/642/kw/10501 it's located somewhere inside the "Merchant Services" tab. After about an hour of search i found it in old interface. When i click it i'm being redirected to "My account".

Please, help me somebody. I'm sick and tired of that buggy, laggy and terribly designed paypal's site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you are logged into developer.paypal.com, click "Applicatons", then click "Sandbox accounts". You see a blue button at the top of the page that says "Create Account". When you create a business account, you will automatically be signed up for PayPal Payments Pro.

You can then grab your API credentials by clicking the "Profile" link from developer.paypal.com.

Edit:

Updating answer with additional information about creating test accounts.

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/lifecycle/ug_sandbox/

Comment: Well, it worked. Great thanks. But what was the problem with first business account? Why PaypalPro was not enabled for it?

Comment: It should have been. If you could send me the email address for the sandbox account that didn't get set-up correctly, I can verify what went wrong. Feel free to shoot me an email at the email address in my profile. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Here is email: spcafemerchant@gmail.com (or spcafemerchant-facilitator@gmail.com) - i dont't know which of them do you need. And thanks again.

Comment: Hello, it appears that we have an issue with the facilitator account not being enabled for Pro in Sandbox. We are working on a fix now. Thanks for helping us idenitfy the issue!